# How to use Design Vision to find area overhead for gate level Verilog code with multiple module?

Tags: verilog

I'm using Design Vision to find area overhead for my FIR circuit, but the code is already in gate level and have more than 1 module. Here's the code

```
module FIR_ori_DW01_add_1 ( A, B, CI, SUM, CO );
  input [7:0] A;
  input [7:0] B;
  output [7:0] SUM;
  input CI;
  output CO;
  wire   \carry[7] , \carry[6] , \carry[5] , \carry[4] , \carry[3] ,
         \carry[2] , \carry[1] ;

  EO3P U1_7 ( .A(A[7]), .B(B[7]), .C(\carry[7] ), .Z(SUM[7]) );
  FA1A U1_6 ( .A(A[6]), .B(B[6]), .CI(\carry[6] ), .CO(\carry[7] ), .S(SUM[6])
         );
  FA1A U1_5 ( .A(A[5]), .B(B[5]), .CI(\carry[5] ), .CO(\carry[6] ), .S(SUM[5])
         );
  FA1A U1_4 ( .A(A[4]), .B(B[4]), .CI(\carry[4] ), .CO(\carry[5] ), .S(SUM[4])
         );
  FA1A U1_3 ( .A(A[3]), .B(B[3]), .CI(\carry[3] ), .CO(\carry[4] ), .S(SUM[3])
         );
  FA1A U1_2 ( .A(A[2]), .B(B[2]), .CI(\carry[2] ), .CO(\carry[3] ), .S(SUM[2])
         );
  FA1A U1_1 ( .A(A[1]), .B(B[1]), .CI(\carry[1] ), .CO(\carry[2] ), .S(SUM[1])
         );
  AN2 U1 ( .A(B[0]), .B(A[0]), .Z(\carry[1] ) );
  EO U2 ( .A(A[0]), .B(B[0]), .Z(SUM[0]) );
endmodule


module FIR_ori_DW01_add_0 ( A, B, CI, SUM, CO );
  input [5:0] A;
  input [5:0] B;
  output [5:0] SUM;
  input CI;
  output CO;
  wire   \A[1] , \A[0] , n1, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11;
  assign SUM[1] = \A[1] ;
  assign \A[1]  = A[1];
  assign SUM[0] = \A[0] ;
  assign \A[0]  = A[0];

  OR2P U2 ( .A(B[3]), .B(A[3]), .Z(n1) );
  AN2P U3 ( .A(n1), .B(n10), .Z(SUM[3]) );
  IV U4 ( .A(A[2]), .Z(n11) );
  IV U5 ( .A(B[5]), .Z(n4) );
  IV U6 ( .A(n10), .Z(n5) );
  EO U7 ( .A(n3), .B(n4), .Z(SUM[5]) );
  AO6 U8 ( .A(n5), .B(n6), .C(n7), .Z(n3) );
  IV U9 ( .A(n8), .Z(n6) );
  EO U10 ( .A(n9), .B(n5), .Z(SUM[4]) );
  NR2 U11 ( .A(n7), .B(n8), .Z(n9) );
  NR2 U12 ( .A(B[4]), .B(A[4]), .Z(n8) );
  AN2 U13 ( .A(B[4]), .B(A[4]), .Z(n7) );
  ND2 U14 ( .A(B[3]), .B(A[3]), .Z(n10) );
  IV U15 ( .A(n11), .Z(SUM[2]) );
endmodule


module FIR_ori_DW02_mult_0 ( A, B, TC, PRODUCT );
  input [3:0] A;
  input [3:0] B;
  output [7:0] PRODUCT;
  input TC;
  wire   \ab[3][2] , \ab[3][1] , \ab[3][0] , \ab[2][3] , \ab[2][2] ,
         \ab[2][1] , \ab[2][0] , \ab[1][3] , \ab[1][2] , \ab[1][1] ,
         \ab[1][0] , \ab[0][3] , \ab[0][2] , \ab[0][1] , \CARRYB[3][2] ,
         \CARRYB[3][1] , \CARRYB[3][0] , \CARRYB[2][2] , \CARRYB[2][1] ,
         \CARRYB[2][0] , \CARRYB[1][2] , \CARRYB[1][1] , \CARRYB[1][0] ,
         \SUMB[3][3] , \SUMB[3][2] , \SUMB[3][1] , \SUMB[2][2] , \SUMB[2][1] ,
         \SUMB[1][2] , \SUMB[1][1] , \A1[4] , \A1[3] , \A1[2] , \A1[1] ,
         \A1[0] , \A2[5] , \A2[4] , \A2[3] , n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11;

  FIR_ori_DW01_add_0 FS_1 ( .A({1'b0, \A1[4] , \A1[3] , \A1[2] , \A1[1] , 
        \A1[0] }), .B({\A2[5] , \A2[4] , \A2[3] , 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0}), .CI(1'b0), .SUM(PRODUCT[7:2]) );
  FA1A S2_2_1 ( .A(\ab[2][1] ), .B(\CARRYB[1][1] ), .CI(\SUMB[1][2] ), .CO(
        \CARRYB[2][1] ), .S(\SUMB[2][1] ) );
  FA1A S1_2_0 ( .A(\ab[2][0] ), .B(\CARRYB[1][0] ), .CI(\SUMB[1][1] ), .CO(
        \CARRYB[2][0] ), .S(\A1[0] ) );
  FA1A S3_2_2 ( .A(\ab[2][2] ), .B(\CARRYB[1][2] ), .CI(\ab[1][3] ), .CO(
        \CARRYB[2][2] ), .S(\SUMB[2][2] ) );
  FA1A S4_1 ( .A(\ab[3][1] ), .B(\CARRYB[2][1] ), .CI(\SUMB[2][2] ), .CO(
        \CARRYB[3][1] ), .S(\SUMB[3][1] ) );
  FA1A S4_0 ( .A(\ab[3][0] ), .B(\CARRYB[2][0] ), .CI(\SUMB[2][1] ), .CO(
        \CARRYB[3][0] ), .S(\A1[1] ) );
  FA1A S5_2 ( .A(\ab[3][2] ), .B(\CARRYB[2][2] ), .CI(\ab[2][3] ), .CO(
        \CARRYB[3][2] ), .S(\SUMB[3][2] ) );
  AN2 U2 ( .A(\CARRYB[3][2] ), .B(\SUMB[3][3] ), .Z(\A2[5] ) );
  EO U3 ( .A(\SUMB[3][3] ), .B(\CARRYB[3][2] ), .Z(\A1[4] ) );
  AN2 U6 ( .A(\CARRYB[3][1] ), .B(\SUMB[3][2] ), .Z(\A2[4] ) );
  EO U7 ( .A(\SUMB[3][2] ), .B(\CARRYB[3][1] ), .Z(\A1[3] ) );
  AN2 U8 ( .A(\CARRYB[3][0] ), .B(\SUMB[3][1] ), .Z(\A2[3] ) );
  EO U9 ( .A(\SUMB[3][1] ), .B(\CARRYB[3][0] ), .Z(\A1[2] ) );
  AN2 U10 ( .A(\ab[0][3] ), .B(\ab[1][2] ), .Z(\CARRYB[1][2] ) );
  EO U11 ( .A(\ab[0][3] ), .B(\ab[1][2] ), .Z(\SUMB[1][2] ) );
  AN2 U12 ( .A(\ab[0][2] ), .B(\ab[1][1] ), .Z(\CARRYB[1][1] ) );
  EO U13 ( .A(\ab[0][2] ), .B(\ab[1][1] ), .Z(\SUMB[1][1] ) );
  AN2 U14 ( .A(\ab[0][1] ), .B(\ab[1][0] ), .Z(\CARRYB[1][0] ) );
  EO U15 ( .A(\ab[0][1] ), .B(\ab[1][0] ), .Z(PRODUCT[1]) );
  NR2 U16 ( .A(n4), .B(n5), .Z(\SUMB[3][3] ) );
  NR2 U17 ( .A(n4), .B(n6), .Z(\ab[3][2] ) );
  NR2 U18 ( .A(n4), .B(n7), .Z(\ab[3][1] ) );
  NR2 U19 ( .A(n4), .B(n8), .Z(\ab[3][0] ) );
  IV U20 ( .A(A[3]), .Z(n4) );
  NR2 U21 ( .A(n5), .B(n9), .Z(\ab[2][3] ) );
  NR2 U22 ( .A(n6), .B(n9), .Z(\ab[2][2] ) );
  NR2 U23 ( .A(n7), .B(n9), .Z(\ab[2][1] ) );
  NR2 U24 ( .A(n8), .B(n9), .Z(\ab[2][0] ) );
  IV U25 ( .A(A[2]), .Z(n9) );
  NR2 U26 ( .A(n5), .B(n10), .Z(\ab[1][3] ) );
  NR2 U27 ( .A(n6), .B(n10), .Z(\ab[1][2] ) );
  NR2 U28 ( .A(n7), .B(n10), .Z(\ab[1][1] ) );
  NR2 U29 ( .A(n8), .B(n10), .Z(\ab[1][0] ) );
  IV U30 ( .A(A[1]), .Z(n10) );
  NR2 U31 ( .A(n5), .B(n11), .Z(\ab[0][3] ) );
  IV U32 ( .A(B[3]), .Z(n5) );
  NR2 U33 ( .A(n6), .B(n11), .Z(\ab[0][2] ) );
  IV U34 ( .A(B[2]), .Z(n6) );
  NR2 U35 ( .A(n7), .B(n11), .Z(\ab[0][1] ) );
  IV U36 ( .A(B[1]), .Z(n7) );
  NR2 U37 ( .A(n8), .B(n11), .Z(PRODUCT[0]) );
  IV U38 ( .A(A[0]), .Z(n11) );
  IV U39 ( .A(B[0]), .Z(n8) );
endmodule


module FIR_ori ( clk, reset, x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, b0, b1, b2, b3, 
        b4, b5, b6, b7, se1, se2, ldTotal, ldMul, Total );
  input [3:0] x0;
  input [3:0] x1;
  input [3:0] x2;
  input [3:0] x3;
  input [3:0] x4;
  input [3:0] x5;
  input [3:0] x6;
  input [3:0] x7;
  input [3:0] b0;
  input [3:0] b1;
  input [3:0] b2;
  input [3:0] b3;
  input [3:0] b4;
  input [3:0] b5;
  input [3:0] b6;
  input [3:0] b7;
  input [2:0] se1;
  input [2:0] se2;
  output [7:0] Total;
  input clk, reset, ldTotal, ldMul;
  wire   n73, n74, n75, n76, n77, n78, n79, n80, n81, n82, n83, n84, n85, n86,
         n87, n88, n89, n90, n91, n92, n93, n94, n95, n96, n97, n98, n99, n100,
         n101, n102, n103, n104, n105, n106, n107, n108, n109, n110, n111,
         n112, n113, n114, n115, n116, n117, n118, n119, n120, n121, n122,
         n123, n124, n125, n126, n127, n128, n129, n130, n131, n132, n133,
         n134, n135, n136, n137, n138, n139, n140, n141;
  wire   [7:0] Mul;
  wire   [7:0] c;
  wire   [7:0] out_alu;
  wire   [3:0] x;
  wire   [3:0] b;

  FD2 \Mul_reg[7]  ( .D(n89), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[7]) );
  FD2 \Mul_reg[6]  ( .D(n88), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[6]) );
  FD2 \Mul_reg[5]  ( .D(n87), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[5]) );
  FD2 \Mul_reg[4]  ( .D(n86), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[4]) );
  FD2 \Mul_reg[3]  ( .D(n85), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[3]) );
  FD2 \Mul_reg[2]  ( .D(n84), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[2]) );
  FD2 \Mul_reg[1]  ( .D(n83), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[1]) );
  FD2 \Mul_reg[0]  ( .D(n82), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Mul[0]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[0]  ( .D(n81), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[0]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[1]  ( .D(n80), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[1]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[2]  ( .D(n79), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[2]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[3]  ( .D(n78), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[3]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[4]  ( .D(n77), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[4]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[5]  ( .D(n76), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[5]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[6]  ( .D(n75), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[6]) );
  FD2 \Total_reg[7]  ( .D(n74), .CP(clk), .CD(n73), .Q(Total[7]) );
  FIR_ori_DW02_mult_0 mult_71 ( .A(x), .B(b), .TC(1'b0), .PRODUCT(c) );
  FIR_ori_DW01_add_1 add_68 ( .A(Mul), .B(Total), .CI(1'b0), .SUM(out_alu) );
  ND4 U81 ( .A(n90), .B(n91), .C(n92), .D(n93), .Z(x[3]) );
  AO2 U82 ( .A(x7[3]), .B(n94), .C(x6[3]), .D(n95), .Z(n93) );
  AO2 U83 ( .A(x5[3]), .B(n96), .C(x4[3]), .D(n97), .Z(n92) );
  AO2 U84 ( .A(x3[3]), .B(n98), .C(x2[3]), .D(n99), .Z(n91) );
  AO2 U85 ( .A(x1[3]), .B(n100), .C(x0[3]), .D(n101), .Z(n90) );
  ND4 U86 ( .A(n102), .B(n103), .C(n104), .D(n105), .Z(x[2]) );
  AO2 U87 ( .A(x7[2]), .B(n94), .C(x6[2]), .D(n95), .Z(n105) );
  AO2 U88 ( .A(x5[2]), .B(n96), .C(x4[2]), .D(n97), .Z(n104) );
  AO2 U89 ( .A(x3[2]), .B(n98), .C(x2[2]), .D(n99), .Z(n103) );
  AO2 U90 ( .A(x1[2]), .B(n100), .C(x0[2]), .D(n101), .Z(n102) );
  ND4 U91 ( .A(n106), .B(n107), .C(n108), .D(n109), .Z(x[1]) );
  AO2 U92 ( .A(x7[1]), .B(n94), .C(x6[1]), .D(n95), .Z(n109) );
  AO2 U93 ( .A(x5[1]), .B(n96), .C(x4[1]), .D(n97), .Z(n108) );
  AO2 U94 ( .A(x3[1]), .B(n98), .C(x2[1]), .D(n99), .Z(n107) );
  AO2 U95 ( .A(x1[1]), .B(n100), .C(x0[1]), .D(n101), .Z(n106) );
  ND4 U96 ( .A(n110), .B(n111), .C(n112), .D(n113), .Z(x[0]) );
  AO2 U97 ( .A(x7[0]), .B(n94), .C(x6[0]), .D(n95), .Z(n113) );
  AN3 U98 ( .A(se1[1]), .B(n114), .C(se1[2]), .Z(n95) );
  AN3 U99 ( .A(se1[1]), .B(se1[0]), .C(se1[2]), .Z(n94) );
  AO2 U100 ( .A(x5[0]), .B(n96), .C(x4[0]), .D(n97), .Z(n112) );
  AN3 U101 ( .A(n114), .B(n115), .C(se1[2]), .Z(n97) );
  AN3 U102 ( .A(se1[0]), .B(n115), .C(se1[2]), .Z(n96) );
  AO2 U103 ( .A(x3[0]), .B(n98), .C(x2[0]), .D(n99), .Z(n111) );
  NR3 U104 ( .A(se1[0]), .B(se1[2]), .C(n115), .Z(n99) );
  NR3 U105 ( .A(n114), .B(se1[2]), .C(n115), .Z(n98) );
  IV U106 ( .A(se1[1]), .Z(n115) );
  AO2 U107 ( .A(x1[0]), .B(n100), .C(x0[0]), .D(n101), .Z(n110) );
  NR3 U108 ( .A(se1[2]), .B(se1[1]), .C(se1[0]), .Z(n101) );
  NR3 U109 ( .A(se1[1]), .B(se1[2]), .C(n114), .Z(n100) );
  IV U110 ( .A(se1[0]), .Z(n114) );
  MUX21H U111 ( .A(Mul[7]), .B(c[7]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n89) );
  MUX21H U112 ( .A(Mul[6]), .B(c[6]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n88) );
  MUX21H U113 ( .A(Mul[5]), .B(c[5]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n87) );
  MUX21H U114 ( .A(Mul[4]), .B(c[4]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n86) );
  MUX21H U115 ( .A(Mul[3]), .B(c[3]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n85) );
  MUX21H U116 ( .A(Mul[2]), .B(c[2]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n84) );
  MUX21H U117 ( .A(Mul[1]), .B(c[1]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n83) );
  MUX21H U118 ( .A(Mul[0]), .B(c[0]), .S(ldMul), .Z(n82) );
  MUX21H U119 ( .A(Total[0]), .B(out_alu[0]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n81) );
  MUX21H U120 ( .A(Total[1]), .B(out_alu[1]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n80) );
  MUX21H U121 ( .A(Total[2]), .B(out_alu[2]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n79) );
  MUX21H U122 ( .A(Total[3]), .B(out_alu[3]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n78) );
  MUX21H U123 ( .A(Total[4]), .B(out_alu[4]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n77) );
  MUX21H U124 ( .A(Total[5]), .B(out_alu[5]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n76) );
  MUX21H U125 ( .A(Total[6]), .B(out_alu[6]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n75) );
  MUX21H U126 ( .A(Total[7]), .B(out_alu[7]), .S(ldTotal), .Z(n74) );
  IV U127 ( .A(reset), .Z(n73) );
  ND4 U128 ( .A(n116), .B(n117), .C(n118), .D(n119), .Z(b[3]) );
  AO2 U129 ( .A(b7[3]), .B(n120), .C(b6[3]), .D(n121), .Z(n119) );
  AO2 U130 ( .A(b5[3]), .B(n122), .C(b4[3]), .D(n123), .Z(n118) );
  AO2 U131 ( .A(b3[3]), .B(n124), .C(b2[3]), .D(n125), .Z(n117) );
  AO2 U132 ( .A(b1[3]), .B(n126), .C(b0[3]), .D(n127), .Z(n116) );
  ND4 U133 ( .A(n128), .B(n129), .C(n130), .D(n131), .Z(b[2]) );
  AO2 U134 ( .A(b7[2]), .B(n120), .C(b6[2]), .D(n121), .Z(n131) );
  AO2 U135 ( .A(b5[2]), .B(n122), .C(b4[2]), .D(n123), .Z(n130) );
  AO2 U136 ( .A(b3[2]), .B(n124), .C(b2[2]), .D(n125), .Z(n129) );
  AO2 U137 ( .A(b1[2]), .B(n126), .C(b0[2]), .D(n127), .Z(n128) );
  ND4 U138 ( .A(n132), .B(n133), .C(n134), .D(n135), .Z(b[1]) );
  AO2 U139 ( .A(b7[1]), .B(n120), .C(b6[1]), .D(n121), .Z(n135) );
  AO2 U140 ( .A(b5[1]), .B(n122), .C(b4[1]), .D(n123), .Z(n134) );
  AO2 U141 ( .A(b3[1]), .B(n124), .C(b2[1]), .D(n125), .Z(n133) );
  AO2 U142 ( .A(b1[1]), .B(n126), .C(b0[1]), .D(n127), .Z(n132) );
  ND4 U143 ( .A(n136), .B(n137), .C(n138), .D(n139), .Z(b[0]) );
  AO2 U144 ( .A(b7[0]), .B(n120), .C(b6[0]), .D(n121), .Z(n139) );
  AN3 U145 ( .A(se2[1]), .B(n140), .C(se2[2]), .Z(n121) );
  AN3 U146 ( .A(se2[1]), .B(se2[0]), .C(se2[2]), .Z(n120) );
  AO2 U147 ( .A(b5[0]), .B(n122), .C(b4[0]), .D(n123), .Z(n138) );
  AN3 U148 ( .A(n140), .B(n141), .C(se2[2]), .Z(n123) );
  AN3 U149 ( .A(se2[0]), .B(n141), .C(se2[2]), .Z(n122) );
  AO2 U150 ( .A(b3[0]), .B(n124), .C(b2[0]), .D(n125), .Z(n137) );
  NR3 U151 ( .A(se2[0]), .B(se2[2]), .C(n141), .Z(n125) );
  NR3 U152 ( .A(n140), .B(se2[2]), .C(n141), .Z(n124) );
  IV U153 ( .A(se2[1]), .Z(n141) );
  AO2 U154 ( .A(b1[0]), .B(n126), .C(b0[0]), .D(n127), .Z(n136) );
  NR3 U155 ( .A(se2[2]), .B(se2[1]), .C(se2[0]), .Z(n127) );
  NR3 U156 ( .A(se2[1]), .B(se2[2]), .C(n140), .Z(n126) );
  IV U157 ( .A(se2[0]), .Z(n140) );
endmodule
```

But for some reason when I read the file it will only read the first module. Therefore I cannot get the full area report for all the modules combined. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to operate on the GUI. Since the topmost module is `FIR_ori`, you can type the following command in the Console command line right at the bottom of the window:

```
current_design FIR_ori
```